# Persistent Scheduled Jobs in Java/Scala with Redis

Tags: java, scala, redis, playframework-2.0

Akka Scheduler is great but lacks persistence.

Is there any good solution for job scheduling with persistence? Preferably Redis.

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/modules/durable-mailbox.html

Comment: @om-nom-nom as Jamie Allen told in his [talk](http://parleys.com/play/51c38461e4b0ed8770356867/chapter0/about), durable mailbox is not a good solution in many cases

Answer (score 2):

One of the best schedulers i know and which we are currently using is [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). Written in Java, but we are using in Scala project alongside with Akka

Comment: Thanks I'll try it. Using any helper library? Can Quartz be integrated with akka scheduler? Cron style it's a little weird and non type safe :(

Comment: @weakwire If you want some Scala DSL for quartz, i didn't find any. As for helper libs, we are using mongo, so there is a [lib](https://github.com/michaelklishin/quartz-mongodb) for easier mongo-quartz comunication. You can check [this](https://github.com/jackywyz/akka-quartz/blob/master/src/main/scala/QuartzActor.scala) this example on using Akka with Quartz. As for scheduler integration, you can use Akka's one for some internal tasks, but it can not replace Quartz scheduler from Quartz completely

Answer (score 0):

Java Quartz is a good option for scheduling and has Jobstore API which can be used for persistence.This is a good read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-quartz/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small Java library I've written recently for handling distributed task scheduling using Redis as the backend: https://github.com/davidmarquis/redis-scheduler

It is very simple but should allow you to get started pretty quickly. It won't persist your job data per-se, but it will trigger your jobs at the right time. Also, if you have multiple instances of your application, jobs will be executed on a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) with Java successfully for a while now and recently added a [redis backend](https://github.com/RedisLabs/redis-quartz).

*disclaimer:* I was involved in the design of redis-quartz. As of now [redis-quartz](https://github.com/RedisLabs/redis-quartz) is still beta.

Answer (score 0):

I know that your question was about Redis, but I just came across [Akka-Scheduling](https://github.com/odd/akkax-scheduling) for Akka and I think it would be useful.

You can use Akka's scheduler with some persistence.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try [Redisson](https://redisson.org). It allows to usual `java.lang.Runnable` and `java.util.concurrent.Callable` interfaces. Here is code example:

```
RScheduledExecutorService executorService = redisson.getExecutorService("myExecutor");
ScheduledFuture<?> future = executorService.schedule(new CallableTask(), 10, 20, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

future.get();
// or cancel it
future.cancel(true);
```

Examples with cron expressions:

```
executorService.schedule(new RunnableTask(), CronSchedule.of("10 0/5 * * * ?"));

executorService.schedule(new RunnableTask(), CronSchedule.dailyAtHourAndMinute(10, 5));

executorService.schedule(new RunnableTask(), CronSchedule.weeklyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(12, 4, Calendar.MONDAY, Calendar.FRIDAY));
```